# Should there not be an option of review as `Approve and edit` in documentation

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

I reviewed some of the posts edits on documentation and I does not found `Approve and edit` option there. Some of the posts were edited **B**ut still need some kind of edit for Example:
grammar or spell mistakes or `Examples` that are meaningful But not formatted well.
So what to do with these kind of posts without `Approve and edit` option ? should these be accepted ?
I think there should be an option of `Approve and edit` like in stackoverflow.